# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when doing a GCI

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a script and am getting a System.UnauthorizedAccessException on this command:

```
gci "\\Media\\recorded tv\" -include *.* -Recurse
```

I can access the directory from Windows Explorer.  When I run the script in PS, I get most of the files, but a few of those errors.

Things I tried:
1) Made sure execution policy was set from elevated (as admin) Powershell
2) Made sure ran PS as admin

If these files are for some reason not accessible, how can I find out which files are not accessible?  Maybe they are hidden/system files?

Comment: The script runs fine directly on the PC (adjusting the path).  It must have to do with the UNC path.  Not sure why though.  I can browse and even delete through Window Explorer through the network.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that individual files/directories have different permissions. Check the security settings on the items `Get-ChildItem` writes errors about.

Comment: It doesn't tell me which files produce the error. That is part of the problem.

Comment: What's in `$Error` when your script is done? Can you post the errors you're seeing?

Comment: It runs without errors. When I ran it on the machine with the drive, it did delete some files.  That is probably why.  I guess I'll have to wait until I get the error again.